# Generating certificate with subjectUniqueID field

Tags: certificate, x509

I would like to generate a certificate with the subjectUniqueID field as indicated in rfc5280( https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280#section-4).I have tried this:

```
openssl req -config myConfigFile.conf -subj "/CN=XXXXX User User/O=MMMMMM/L=mylocation/ST=Italy/C=IT/subjectUniqueID=hash/" -new -key myPem.pem -out MyCsr.csr
```

How is it done?are there other alternative libraries(python) or methods I can use to achieve this?

Comment: is there any particular reason to use this field? As per RFC 5280 §4.1.2.8, `CAs conforming to this profile MUST NOT generate certificates with unique identifiers`. In other words, they are discouraged for use.

Comment: The v2 fields {subject,issuer}UniqueID are not attributes and cannot go in the subject _or_ issuer DistinguishedName fields. These fields are not supported by OpenSSL, thus not by things using OpenSSL such as python. There is an X.520 attribute `x500UniqueIdentifier` which standards allow in a DN, but it has ASN.1 type BITSTRING so OpenSSL _commandline_ doesn't support it; libcrypto does, and it can be accessed from python `cryptography.x509`, see https://cryptography.io/en/latest/x509/reference/#cryptography.x509.NameAttribute and #cryptography.x509.oid.NameOID.X500_UNIQUE_IDENTIFIER

Comment: "is there any particular reason to use this field?" it's for test purposes,i have to test that the system am sending this certificate rejects it if it contains the subject unique identifier.Any methods is okay for me as i am not obligated to use openssl